# Reference request: Geometric Limit

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, manifolds

In [this video](https://youtu.be/ImIQP9szMGs?t=49m58s), prof. J.Morgan explains the idea of what he calls "Geometric Limit". He says that it is a notion of convergence stronger than that of the Gromov-Hausdorff distance.

Can someone give me a reference (such as a book) where this geometric limit is dealt with in detail?

Moreover, can someone give me an insight as to in which way this limit is related to the Gromov-Hausdorff one, and as to what the fact that the latter is weaker entails (I just need the idea, not necessarily a proof)?

Comment: I haven't watched the video, but Morgan is most likely referring to Cheeger-Gromov convergence, which is defined in terms of Riemannian metrics rather than just distance metrics (like Gromov-Hausdorff). You should be able to find this in most books on Ricci flow - for example it's chapter 8 of [this book](http://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~andrews/book.pdf). I don't remember the relevant sense in which this is "stronger" than G-H convergence.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I was looking for!